# How to create a polyline/polygon around building or specific place using google map api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

[image: **Polyline around building**]

**Anybody knows how to create a polyline/polygon around building or specific place as shown in above image using google map api v2.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like geo-fencing.  If so you should follow the Google API documentation on how to draw markers for it.

Comment: Yeah bro it looks like geo-fencing only. Whenever my current location is at big place or some famous place like railway station, airport, mall or building they geofenced that place like that. Is there any google API to get boundary geocodes of that place based on current location.

Answer (score 3):

Get the Latitude and Longitude of required points and use below code to draw polygon.

```
GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add polygon in the area
 Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(Lat1, Lon1), new LatLng(Lat2, Lon2), new LatLng(Lat3, Lon3), new LatLng(Lat4, Lon4))
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Its up to you to get the required Latitude and Longitude of targeted area

Comment: Bro, is it possible to draw the same shape/polygon based on current latitude and longitude only.

Comment: Yes . addPolygon method just needs input of Different latitude and longitude. No matter from where you get those

Comment: @ Stallion Can you help me how to find all latitude longitude of specific area for example railway station

Comment: As this is not at all related to current question. I would suggest you to put up a new question. And accept and close this question if solution suits your current requirement